# How to display an image in a view if a variable is negative

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a view I am creating a table like so:

```
<% @businesses.each do |b| %>
<td>
 <%= b.value %>
</td>
```

I have 3 images:

```
green-up.png
red-down.png
circle.png
```

I want to show the green up arrow if b.value is positive, the circle if it is 0, and the red down arrow if it's negative.

Example if positive:

```
<td>
 <img src='green-up.png'>12
</td>
<td>
 <img src='circle.png'>0
</td>
```

I'm creating a report so there are a lot of these checks. Is there a better way than using a whole bunch of if statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good place to start would be a helper.

```
# app/helpers/businesses_helper.rb
module BusinessesHelper
  def business_icon_for(value)
    if value > 0
      image_tag 'green-up.png', alt: 'Positive'
    elsif value == 0
      image_tag 'circle.png', alt: 'No change'
    else
      image_tag 'red-down.png', alt: 'Negative'
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<% @businesses.each do |b| %>
  <td>
    <%= business_icon_for b.value %>12
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= business_icon_for b.value %>0
  </td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create an instance method in your `Business` model:

```
def image
  return 'green-up.png' if value > 0
  return 'red-down.png' if value < 0
  'circle.png'
end
```

And then in your view

```
<img src='<%= b.image %>'>
```

Comment: I don't agree that the model should ever know anything about images or other assets unless you're working with user uploads (i.e., through something like Paperclip or Carrierwave).

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this simply by modifying your **entity bean**,
Just add an attribute in entity bean **image name** along with **value** 
Image name you can set to the bean while setting value for the bean based on value(negative,zero or positive) .

Then in view you don't need to make any code for choosing the right image,
just iterate though the list of entity beans and append the below code in html.

```
<td>
  <img src='<%= b.image %>'><%= b.value %>
</td>
```

Comment: I don't agree that the model should ever know anything about images or other assets unless you're working with user uploads (i.e., through something like Paperclip or Carrierwave).